# Can I install Ubuntu Desktop 12.10 on laptop Samsung NP300E5X-S01AE?

Tags: installation, 12.10

I've tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, but I have problem
after I tried to install it the laptop stop working and no BIOS screen 
I get back to warranty center and they changed the motherboard :(
What should I do to make the install work?

**Specifications**

**Processor** : 
Brand/Family :  Intel Core i5-3210M
CPU Speed : 2.5GHz
Cache Memory :  3MB
Turbo Boost :   3.1GHz

**"RAM" Memory** : 
RAM Type :  DDR3
Installed RAM : 4Gb
RAM FSB speed : 1600MHz
RAM Up to : 8GB

**Drives** : 
Hard Drive Type :   HDD
Hard Drive Capacity :   500Gb
Rotational speed(RPM) : 5400RPM
Hard Drive Connection : SATA
CD/DVD Drive :  DVD Super Multi DL
Memory card reader :    SD, SDHC, SDXC Card Reader

**Graphic Card** : 
VGA Brand : NVIDIA
VGA Model : GeForce GT 610M
VGA Dedicated Memory :  1GB
VGA Memory Type :   DDR3

**Screen :** 
Screen Type :   LED backlight
Screen Resolution : 1366x768Px
Screen Size :   15.6inch
High Definition :   HD

**Internet** : 
Bluetooth : Bluetooth v 4.0
LAN :   10/100/1000 BASE-T Ethernet
WiFi :  WiFi 802.11 b/g/n

**Interface** : 
USB :   3xUSB 2.0
HDMI :  1xHDMI
VGA/Out :   Yes
Audio Ports :   Yes

**Multimedia** : 
Speaker :   Yes
Web Camera :    1.3MP
Microphone :    Yes
Touch Pad : Yes

**Software** : 
Operating System :  FreeDOS

**Battery** : 
Battery tech/cells :    6-cell Lithium-Ion
charger :   AC Power Adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it really had a motherboard hardware problem, then it seems unlikely that its failure had anything to do with your installation of ubuntu. My suggestion would be to boot into ubuntu via a livecd or a liveusb. This way you can see how ubuntu works without actually going through the full install. You will be able to see if are any hardware compatibility issues and such. It will boot slower and may run slower from CD/USB than a harddrive install will, but it will give you an idea of what a full install will look like.

Also, are you sure you should use a 64bit version? 32bit works on 64s but not vice versa (as far as I know...)

Good luck!

Comment: "32bit works on 64s but not vice versa" < True.

Answer (score 1):

Explain your question a little better. What exactly happened the the laptop that it stopped working? And as far as the specs go, you may need a driver for the webcam but It looks like it should work.